# Should I create a unique Apple App ID per application for the App Store?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Should I create a unique App ID per application for the App Store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the "Bundle identifier" should be unique for each applications. This doesn't mean that there should be unique "App ID" created for each application. Its not necessary to create different App IDs for different applications. You can use a single App ID with asterisk(*) as wild-card character to specify different bundle identifiers.

The Doc says,

> If you are creating a suite of applications that will share the same Keychain access (e.g. sharing passwords between applications) or have no Keychain Access requirements, you can create a single App ID for your entire application suite utilizing a trailing asterisk as a wild-card character.
>
> In these wild-card situations, you’ll simply replace the asterisk with whatever string you wish in the CF Bundle Identifier field in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks. So what's the significance of an 'App ID' then?

Comment: As I mentioned, the Bundle ID/App ID of each app should be unique. For example, if the App ID you created is "com.domainname.*" and in your first app you have specified the bundle identifier as "com.domainname.abc" then you can not give the same bundle ID for any other app. This should be unique. But you can use something like "com.domainname.xyz" as your another apps bundle ID. But if you create you App ID as "com.domainname.abc" you can use this App ID for only one app. You have to new App ID in developer portal for your another apps.

Answer (score 0):

The short awnser is Yes. One app per AppID.

Comment: Or for a group of similar apps, he can have a different bundle identifier using the same app id.

Comment: That would be possible aswell indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Offcourse you must create unique App-id for each Application.

This below link will help you a lot for how to create an app id.

http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/bundles/howto.action