# Version 1.0 for iPad whereas 1.1 on itunes for same app

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have got in a very strange situation. I have made 2 different apps for iPad and iPhone with same name, the iPhone version is currently on app-Store. Now I have to upload the app for iPad , but problem is that th iphone version has been updated to 1.1 .
Can I upload a new app with version 1.1 for the first time. the version is main concern here as my webservices use version to control the data output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can upload a new app with version number 1.1. But during its next updation you have to provide higher version number to the app.

Comment: will I use the same appID as used in the iPhone app?

Comment: with app-ID you are  referring to bundle-identifier then no you have to use different app-id as each app his unique app id and you cannot use the same app-id for other app

Comment: yes I am referring to Bundle Identifier but its the iPad version for thesame app whose iphone version is currently on the app store.

Comment: that's it you have to give a different bundle-identifier as the one is already associated with iPhone app. chk this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724425/same-bundle-id-suffix-on-ipad-and-iphone-versions-of-app

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436517/should-i-create-a-unique-apple-app-id-per-application-for-the-app-store